# typdef enum issue

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, typedef

What I am looking at is probably a simple issue, but still could not figure out what is wrong with the code:

in header file(.h) im declaring this:

```
typedef enum {
    ActivityTaskAdd = 1,
    ActivityAppointmentAdd = 2,
    ActivityContactAdd = 3,
} OfflineRelationshipType;
```

and in .m file in a method I am doing

```
OfflineRelationshipType* relationType;
switch(relationType) {
```

but getting error on switch statement as shown below

[image]
}
This should be straight forward but still cant see what i am missing.

EDIT: I also tried :

```
   @property (assign) OfflineRelationshipType* relationType;
```

instead of declaring relationType before switch statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
OfflineRelationshipType relationType;
```

You made pointer to that, while `switch` expects integer values.

Comment: Damn! that made the error go away. But now getting warning "Variable 'relationType' in uninitialized when used here."

Comment: you haven't initialized it. use it as `relationType=ActivityTaskAdd`

Comment: I want to use ActivityTaskAdd, ActivityAppointmentAdd as switch cases, so adding relationType = ActivityTaskAdd will be true for only that case.

Comment: need ++ operator or use loop to iterate.